# How can I access a file in a build step generated by another build in another jenkins workspace

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a file vstore.txt generated by a build step by a job recurring every 30 min. I want to be able to access this file from another job in a build step and store it to a variable. How can I do this?

I'm able to view `https://<jenkinsurl>/<folder>/job/<nameofjob>/ws/vstore.txt` via the jenkins url. How can I store this data as a variable in a different build step of another job?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file content via [HTTP Request Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/), and write to your current job's workspace, or directly use the content in build step.